# Changing C source code in an R package

Tags: c, r

I am pretty new to R. 
If I want to change a C source code in an R package, do I need to uninstall and install the R package every time I change the C code? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you do not need to explicitly uninstall a package. You can install only the C library (provided there are no changes in the R code), e.g., `R CMD INSTALL --libs-only MyPkg` or `R CMD INSTALL --libs-only --no-test-load MyPkg`. Likely you'll start a new R session, typically with some kind of test script `R -f my_test.R`. See `R --help` and `R CMD INSTALL --help`.